# React native npm start: resp.asserted-states is not iterable

Tags: windows, react-native

i have just tried to create new react native project using the guide here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

but i'm unable to run the metro packager.

```
PS D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject> npm start

> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 start
> react-native start


                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
                  ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
                 ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
                 ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
                  ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


                Welcome to Metro v0.76.5
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: resp.asserted-states is not iterable
    at Object.onSubscribe [as cb] (D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\WatchmanWatcher.js:174:31)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\fb-watchman\index.js:103:15)
    at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at BunserBuf.process (D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\bser\index.js:292:10)
    at D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\bser\index.js:247:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\WatchmanWatcher.js:107:12)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\fb-watchman\index.js:111:12)
    at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at D:\Sources\Personal\AwesomeProject\node_modules\bser\index.js:249:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

Operating System: Windows 11
NodeJS: 18.16.1

Apparently if i try in WSL, it works just fine with the same node js version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently after consulting with the facebook metro github repo in this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1022
the problem was because of my watchman is too old version `4.9.4` where the latest watchman is `2023.04.17.00`. So upgrading the watchman fixed the issue

Comment: How did you update the watchman?

Comment: for windows, you can simply download the latest watchman in: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install